# Can't update score of any other user but myself

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This is my first attempt to write a game app. It is a simple quiz that generates a score in the end.

I have the app in sandbox mode and I have two test users (real people, not test accounts) on top of myself.

The app is mainly written in javascript, apart from the piece of code  that does the score updating where i use a php page in order to avoid exposing my app access_token.

In this page I run something like:

`$facebook->api('/USER_ID/scores/', 'POST', array('access_token' => APP_ACCESS_TOKEN, 'score' => $score));`

This updates the score when I use the app myself, but not when the other users do.

Apparently there is a permission issue at play here, but I cannot find which one. All users have granted to the app the `publish_actions` permission.

Any ideas?

Update: The question is invalid. nothing to do with the api call or permissions. See comment below.

Comment: are you updating the app_access_token, everytime before calling the api?

Comment: No. I could, but the app_access_token doesn't change if the app secret stays the same. Why you think it matters?

Comment: well you are right that the token doesn't need to be updated. I'm just making a guess here, are you checking the return value after the call? are you getting some error? how did you come to the conclusion that its a permission error?

Comment: I found what was wrong. Nothing to do with the api call. There was a problem in the code before the call, that was returning an undefined score for the other users. Thanks for taking the time to look into this @DroidUser though.